# How to read a txt file and use its data to compare it with other variables?

Tags: variables, count

I want to create a program, which reads 2 txt files. The first txt file is a logfile, the second is a short one with names. The task is to read both of the files, and count the specific names(from the second txt) in the first txt.

Comment: What programming language are You using? What have You tried so far?

Comment: Do you have to read specific names from the second file and write to the first file or read the specific names from both files? Which programming language you want to use?

Comment: I'm using python 3.  The names from the second text should be counted in the first text. I want to use it for examination for example: if one of the specified names are appear more than three times in the first text, something happens